# Mysql, search in multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm working on an async game, but I'm totally new to MySQL and PHP. I have two tables, tb_users and tb_matches. The first one stores all users and their status (for example, a value of 0 in the 'status' column means the player is in stand-by, while a value of 1 means the player is waiting for an opponent to play a match).

The tb_matches table stores all the matches, both active and inactive (completed) ones. There are two columns in this table with player IDs.

What I am trying to do is to perform a search for an available opponent, which must fulfill these requirements:

1) it must have a status of 1 in the tb_users table
2) it must not already have an active match with the user searching for a new opponent

I've tried with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_users
JOIN tb_matches
WHERE tb_users.status = "1"
AND tb_matches.player1 != '".$username."'
AND tb_matches.player2 != '".$username."'
```

..but it's not giving me any result. Also, it should take into account that in the tb_matches table, there could be no matches at all.

Any help? Also, is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Try running your mysql thru http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm to see ifit is even structured correctly   Then attack the problem!

Comment: Can you please show the columns in each table? For example, in your `tb_matches` table, what column stores the active/inactive status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following alternate table structure:

```
tb_users
---------
id
name
seeking


tb_user_matches
---------------
match_id
player_id


tb_matches
----------
id
started
ended
status
```

- Adding a third (many-to-many) table to store which players are involved in which match allows simpler queries, see below.
- Change "status" in `tb_users` to "seeking" so a boolean data type makes sense.
- Don't store player *names* in `tb_matches`, store their ID. (Allows name changes without breaking links ([Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)).)
- Consider adding datetime fields to `tb_matches` to store the match start and end date; it might be useful in the future.
- The "status" column in `tb_matches` can indicate three match statuses: waiting for more players, in progress, or completed (see below).

With this structure, you can use the following query to find players that are:

- Searching for a match (seeking = 1)
- Not already in a match that is waiting for players

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM tb_users u
    LEFT JOIN tb_user_matches um
        JOIN tb_matches m
        ON um.match_id = m.id AND m.status = 0
    ON u.id = um.player_id
WHERE u.seeking = 1
AND um.match_id IS NULL;
```

I am proposing `tb_matches.status` could be "0" for inactive (waiting for players), "1" for active, and "2" for completed.

This does not necessarily check if the player is already engaged in an active match. Perhaps your game allows players to participate in multiple simultaneous matches? If not, you can alter the query to exclude matches that are active as well (change `m.status = 0` to `m.status != 2`).

**Edit:**

To explain the query in English (as best I can):

Select user id and name from the users table. Include matches that the user is involved where the match status is "0" (waiting). (The `LEFT JOIN` makes it so if the user is not involved in any matches with status "0", the match_id will be empty (null).)

Now, from this set of data, only show users that are seeking (`u.seeking = 1`), and aren't in a waiting match (`um.match_id IS NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note that you will have to substitute 'username' for the actual user name)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_users 
WHERE Username != 'username'
AND status = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                FROM tb_matches 
                WHERE (player1 = 'username' OR player2 = 'username')
                AND Status = 'inactive')
```

Comment: That did it! I only had to change this `WHERE Username = 'username'` to this `WHERE Username != 'username'`

Comment: I don't think this is working... Can you explain me this algorithm?

Comment: Yeah, it was working until I added a new match with another pair of users (with different IDs from 'username'). Now it's not working anymore.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    `tb_users`
WHERE
    `tb_users`.`status` = "1"
AND
    `tb_users`.`name` NOT IN (
        SELECT `player1` FROM `tb_matches` WHERE `player2` = 'username'
        UNION
        SELECT `player2` FROM `tb_matches` WHERE `player1` = 'username'
        UNION
        SELECT 'username'
    )
```

Comment: You can't put an alias after `NOT IN`, AFAIK. You need to put the subquery there.

Comment: You can't refer to an alias like that. An alias is not a view.

Comment: Nope, the logic is okay, but with subquery it is very slow... Mysql really sux...

Comment: Fantastic :D I still hate mysql :D

Comment: Can you please explain this one?

Comment: Yepp. There is a subquery after the NOT IN which collects all the opponents the user already played with, and the user itself... In the main query it simply selects the users which have active status and are not selected by the subquery. The only problem with this that the subquery runs by every user, so it can be slow... You should create a mysql view for the subquery if you want a faster version of this.

Comment: mmm...but a new match with a player you already played with (and completed) should be possible

Comment: I don't think so. The 'username' is the user who is looking for opponents, so you have to inject the name parameter there. But for god sake don't use php templates for that, use pdo or mysqli prepared statements instead of that.

Comment: Btw using the user_name as index is a bad idea too... Every user should have an user id which is an auto increment integer. (mysql works faster with integers) You should set that as primary key, and use foreign keys - which refer to the user_id - in the matches table by the player1 and player2 column. Try out mysql workbench, it is a great tool to edit your database. I use now workbench version 5.2.

Comment: looks like there's an error in the code above, `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION (SELECT `player2` ' at line 7`

Comment: Ok, I'll create a test database, and try it out.

Comment: Now the SQL is ok, btw I think you should concider to accept JYelton 's answer as solution because it describes what you should use instead of your current - bad designed - database structure.

Comment: Yes, I was pointing to JYelton's answer, but since I'm here to learn, I wanted to know what was wrong in the code above, too. Thank you.